# logistics AP calc bc 2004 question 5

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> A population is modeled by a function $P$ that satisfies the logistic differential equation $\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{P}{5}(1-\frac{P}{12})$.
>   If $P(0) = 3$, for what value of $P$ is the population growing the fastest?

Since the population starts at 3, I thought the point would be the 'midpoint' between the minimum and maximum, and since the logistics graph approaches 12, I thought it would be $(12+3)/2 = 7.5$. But apparently, the answer is $6$. Why is that?

Comment: have you solved the equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : Solving this diffferential equation is considerably more than what needs to be done to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the maximum rate of growth (which is derivative of $P$)
$$P'(t)=-P^2/60+P/5=-\frac{1}{60}(P-6)^2+\frac{3}{5}$$
Obviously, the maximum is reached when $P=6 $

Answer (score 1):

The growth rate is $\dfrac{dP}{dt},$ which is equal to

$$
\frac P 5 \left( 1-\frac P {12} \right) = \frac 1 {60} P \left( 12-P \right)
$$

Since the graph of $P\mapsto P(12-P)$ is a parabola, and thus symmetric about its axis, and has $P$-intercepts at $0$ and at $12,$ its highest point must be halfway between $P=0$ and $P=12.$

You say it "starts" at $3.$ But notice that as $t\to+\infty$ you have $P\to12,$ and as $t\to-\infty$ you get $P\to0.$ So the kind of symmetric you consider would suggest a number halfway between $0$ and $12.$